# Are these two 'that's relative pronouns? If then, what is the antecedent of each of them?

Tags: antecedents

Was there some move **that** is beyond what was being presented to me **that** maybe a Churchill could have seen, or an Eisenhower might have figured out? - [Barack Obama](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/09/22/politics/obama-syria-civil-war-haunts/)

Comment: What research have you done? I'll give you a hint - there is only one antecedent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are two relative pronouns. The move is the antecedent of both thats.

The main clause:

> Was there some move?

relative clause 1:

> **the move** is beyond what was being presented to me

relative clause 2:

> Maybe a Churchill could have seen or an Eisenhower could have figured out **the move**.

The relative pronoun that replaces "the move" in both clauses which are then used to describe move in the main clause.